# Use Jar or Jad files with Blackberry Simulator

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I know jad files can be installed via OTA if my set is BES 3.6 compatible.
Can I upload a jar or jad file to my BlackBerry simulator, instead of the cod file?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes "OTA download" is possible on the Blackberry simulator just enter the link to the .jad file into your Blackberry Browser.

Comment: I know that OTA is possible.But my jad n jar files r in my local system.So how will i give the link in my browser

Answer (score 3):

You can create a SDcard file system for simulator and install the app cod, jad files to simulator:
You can set the SDCard location for your simulator, copy the app cod(its extracted siblings if cod file size is more than 64kb) with its jad file(make sure the cod and jad files are in same folder). Now browse SDcard location from your simulator and select the jad file for installing the app.

To Browse the SDcard loc from simulator:
Go into Media>Click on Menu>Select Explorer>then Select Memory card and browse to required location.

Setting the SDcard for simulator:
For Eclipse:
Right click on project>Run as>Run configuration>select simulator tab>select Memory tab>Check Use file system for SDcard files>Click on Browse to select the location.

For BB JDE:
Click Edit>Preferences>Select Simulator tab>Select Memory Tab>further steps are same as done in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for replying.By the what is the procedure to accept the answer?Anyways,i have uploaded the jad,jar n cod files(which i extracted through rapc) into a server.Now when i try to install via OTA,jar file installs fine.Jad file says Push Registration Failed,and cod file installation says No Content type found.So cannot process the request.Can anyone explain me what is going wrong

Comment: Why only jar file gets installed properly but not jad and cod

Comment: I never tried of installing the jar file onto blackberry device or simulator. According to my knowledge the rapc is the blackberry compiler which compiles your app and generates single cod file. For deploying the app via OTA you required the cod and jad file generated when u compile/run the app. Now if cod file size is >64kb then app will not install. So you have to extract its sibling by winrar/winzip software. Just right click on cod file>select open with winrar>Now select Extract to and specify location. Now copy those exacted cod files and jad to one folder and upload it to server.

Comment: Now you can have one html file with download link and this link will point to jad file. When you access this page via device/simulator browser and click on that link, the link will call the jad file and the jad file internally will call the cod file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.Can anyone tell me the procedure to accept answer in StackOverFlow